# How to create a re-usable angular 2 component (library)

Tags: angular

1. I have a simple angular component created using angular CLI (ng new component-name, this has the sample module).
2. Published the component-name to my private npm repository.
3. ***ng build*** is used to create the distribution file - dist/ mySampleComponent.js
   :
   :
4. Created another simple angular application using angular CLI.
5. Did a npm install to install the module component-name
6. The module was copied successfully to the angular application under node_modules/@private-repo/component-name
7. When I import { SampleModule } from  '@private-repo/component-name' in my AppModule ; I get the following error

Module '".../node_modules/@private-repo/component-name/dist/mySampleComponent"' has no exported member 'SampleModule'.

any thoughts?

Comment: Seems like you might be using angular in a way that's not exactly standard. Angular is a framework for developing single page web-apps, and isn't set up for creating standalone npm modules. After you build a web-app using `ng build` it's just a single page web-app.

Comment: in sample.module in the section exports:[...] put your module and component

Answer (score 0):

*"ng build is used to create the distribution file - dist/ mySampleComponent.js"*

I suspect this is where you are going wrong.

When you `build` an angular project, it compiles typescript to javascript. Javascript does not have Modules or Components as they get transmuted into native javascript / webpack code.

The reason that you are getting the error ...

```
 Module '".../node_modules/@private-repo/component-name/dist/mySampleComponent"' has no exported member 'SampleModule'.`
```

... is because your `mySampleComponent.js` no longer contains the relevant Module decorators / metadata identifiable by the angular transpiler.

---

If you go into an angular project and flick through some of the pre-compilation imports in `node_modules` such as those in `@angular/core` or `rxjs` etc you will see that these all include typescript files. Compare this to those which are used post compilation and you can see that they only contain `.js` files. This is due to the aforementioned.

Comment: Shouldn't the following compiler options {'"target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015"} in ts-configuration be enough to spit the final bundle suited for any browsers

Answer (score 0):

1. ng build simply compiles typescript and spits javascript
2. To get a transpiled version of Javascript we can use the compiler 'ngc'
3. If your code includes css and html, then we need additional bundle API like webpack

So In order to build an angular library we need ngc + webpack (SystemJS, gulp or any other build framework)